# Forcing exact boundaries in matplotlib's histogram

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

If I feed a collection of values to matplotlib's histogram, I get a min and max boundary that has been rounded to a nice number.

E.g. if I feed values between -1 and 18.4, my histogram axis will run from -10 to 50.

Is there a way to force the axis to be a perfect fit for the data, without padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `range` attribute to adjust the range in which the histogram buckets are created, and use `xlim` to control the exact range displayed on the x-axis.

```
from pylab import hist, xlim

hist(np.random.random(100) * 100, range=(5,90))
xlim(5,90)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I tried the xlim alone before, which is not sufficient, despite what the docs say on the range parameter: 'If not provided, range is (x.min(), x.max())' which it seems is NOT true.